# Mac Mail - Mountain Lion - How does one remove the name from the sender heading?

Tags: macos, email

Instead of From: listing { "Name"  }  and showing up on recipients email as such,   I would like to only have the email address shoe up so the above would be  -  { ,xxx@yyyy.zz }.

I have three domains I send and receive from I would like to keep one of them private, without my name showing.

Thanks
iciarch

Answer (score 1):

Mail (menu) > Preferences... > Accounts > select the target account and under Account Information in the Full Name: field put the email address not the full name.